# 2D rectangle should stop moving when colliding

Tags: c#, collision, detection, rectangles

I have created two Rectangles, you can move and jump with one of them, and the other one is standing still on the Form as an obstacle.
I want the obstacle to work as an obstacle(or a wall if you will), basically I want the movable rectangle to stop when its right side is colliding with the obstacle's left side(and so forth).

I found this code how to **NOT** detect collision(because it's apparently easier to not detect collision)between two rectangles in an article:

```
OutsideBottom = Rect1.Bottom < Rect2.Top
OutsideTop = Rect1.Top > Rect2.Bottom
OutsideLeft = Rect1.Left > Rect2.Right
OutsideRight = Rect1.Right < Rect2.Left
//or
return NOT (
(Rect1.Bottom < Rect2.Top) OR
(Rect1.Top > Rect2.Bottom) OR
(Rect1.Left > Rect2.Right) OR
(Rect1.Right < Rect2.Left) )
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it. I have a bool called "player1.left" which becomes true when I press 'A' on the keyboard('D' to move to the right, and 'W' to jump)which when true will move the rectangle 10 pixels to the left(in the Timer_Tick event).

**EDIT:**

"rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2)" works to detect collision. But how would I use that(what should go inside the if-statement) if I want the movable rectangle to stop moving to the right(but still be able to jump and move to the left)if its right side collides with the obstacle's left side(and so forth)?

Comment: Is there a `Rectangle.Intersects()` method in that `Rectangle` implementation? If so: `bool collided = rect1.Intersects(rect2);`

Comment: "because it's apparently easier to not detect collision". Wouldn't say it is easier, but faster. It stops checking the rest of the values. Faster to continually check 1 condition every update versus 4.

Answer (score 1):

//UPDATE
Let's say you have the class PlayableCharacter which inherits from Rectangle.

```
public class PlayableCharacter:Rectangle {

  //position in a cartesian space
  private  int _cartesianPositionX;
  private  int _cartesianPositionY;

  //attributes of a rectangle
  private  int _characterWidth;
  private  int _characterHeight;

  private bool _stopMoving=false;


    public PlayableCharacter(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
       this._cartesianPositionX=x;
       this._cartesianPositionY=y;
       this._chacterWidth=width;
       this._characterHeight=height;
    }

    public bool DetectCollision(PlayableCharacter pc, PlayableCharacter obstacle)
    {

     // this a test in your method
        int x=10;
        if (pc.IntersectsWith(obstacle)){
            Console.Writeline("The rectangles touched");
            _stopMoving=true;
            ChangeMovingDirection(x);
            StopMoving(x);
        }

    }

   private void ChangeMovingDirection(int x)
   {
     x*=-1;
     cartesianPositionX+=x;
   }


  private void StopMoving(int x)
  {

     x=0;
     cartesianPositionX+=x;
  }
```

}

In the code I`ve given you, in a situation when the character is going to the right, the x value which is positive, the character will face the other direction. If he moves on the left,  if he collides with an obstacle, he will then face the other direction.

With StopMoving, even though you make a script which runs over time in a loop for example, it will never make the character move.

I think this should give the basis for your work. If there are any issues, please comment on the solution I wrote and I'll do my best to help you out if it's in my reach.

Comment: @Anders23 usually, when you make an object move, it's because you're modifying the values of the pixels of its location. When you use my code, you can just stop the process.

Comment: How would the code look like if I want the movable rectangle to stop moving to the right(but still be able to jump and move to the left)if its right side collides with the obstacle's left side(and so forth)?

Comment: If the answer that was provided helps you in any way or is actually was you were looking for, mark it as the answer so others will know in the future! :) @Anders23